# Puppeteer scraping nextPage

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I can't seem to make my Puppeteer script scrape one new page at a time. It seems to scrape page2 and 3 several times. Can someone help me fix this?

Right now my Code is this:

```
   import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
   
   
   (async () => {
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       headless: false,
     });
     const page = await browser.newPage();
   
   
     // Go to the initial page
     await page.goto('https://clerk.house.gov/Votes');
   
     let hasNextPage = true;
   
     while (hasNextPage) {
       const nextButton = await page.waitForSelector('a[aria-label="Next"] span[class~="fa"]', { timeout: 5000 }).catch(() => null);
       if (nextButton) {
         console.log('Processing page:', page.url());
   
         // Place your code to extract data or perform actions on the current page here
   
         await nextButton;
         await nextButton.click('a[aria-label="Next"] span[class~="fa"]');
         await page.waitForNavigation();
       } else {
         hasNextPage = false;
       }
     }
   
     await browser.close();
   })();
```

And the results are:

And the results look like this:

```
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes#
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=2
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=2#
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=2#
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=3
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=3#
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=3#
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=3
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=3#
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=3#
Processing page: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes?page=3
file:///Users/amitkumar/Desktop/Puppeteer_project/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/api/ElementHandle.js:577
throw new Error(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have redirect first, so `waitForNavigation` doesn't work correct - it only waits for url to be changed.

This is not nice solution, but this would work (I provide you part of code after declaring nextButton

```js
const url = page.url();
if (nextButton) {
        console.log('Processing page:', url);

        // Place your code to extract data or perform actions on the current page here

const pageNumber = url.includes('?')
          ? Number(url.split('=')[1].replace('#', ''))
          : 1;
await nextButton.click();
await browser.waitForTarget((t) =>
          t.url().endsWith(`?page=${pageNumber + 1}`),
        );
```

Also be aware that in you implementation you're not getting last page (on page before last next button is disappeared), so you need to handle this case.